# Achieving nanosecond accuracy with MKR Vidor 4000

Tags: oscillator-clock

Can I achieve nanosecond accuracy with Arduino Vidor MKR 4000? Has anyone experience? Obviously by using the FPGA it has on it. I do not find much support on this module on google search...

Comment: do you know what frequency is involved in 1 ns time interval?

Comment: I think so..., but we are talking for FPGA here...I think they have different rationale than CPUs, don't they?

Comment: what are you trying to build?  ... do you know what an FPGA actually is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't.

To achieve 1ns precision you need a 1GHz clock. That can't happen.  The MKR Vidor 4000 uses an FPGA with an "A7" speed grade. That means that (according to Table 20 [here](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/hb/cyclone-10/c10lp-51002.pdf)) you can't run at any more than 402Mhz internally (200MHz is all Arduino are rating it for).

Not even half.

Around 5ns precision would be the absolute maximum precision you could get if you stick to the Arduino clock specs.